# Whether redis scan will scan data inserted after scan operation started?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I am using the redis scan to iterate over the key in my redis DB.This is the code i am using

```
#example :1

start_cursor=0

r=redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port=6379)
cur, keys = r.scan(cursor=start_cursor, match='*', count=3)
records=len(keys)
values=[]
values.extend(i for i in keys)
print cur,records,values


while cur != 0:
        cur, keys = r.scan(cursor=cur, match='*', count=3)
        records+=len(keys)
        data = r.mget(keys=keys)
        values.extend(i for i in keys)
        print cur, len(keys),values

print "Total records scanned :{}".format(records)
```

My DB has following values in the format (key,values) (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)(5,5)

When I am scanning my records with

```
start_cursor=0
```

I am getting the following records

```
scan #=>Cursor,new records,all records

scan  #1 =>5,3,['1', '2', '5']
scan  #2 =>0,2,['1', '2', '5', '3', '4']
Total Records scanned :5
```

when I am starting the scanning with my cursor number from scan #1 say(5).I am getting the records from the scan #2 in my example 1

```
Example : 2
start_cursor=5
```

```
scan #=>Cursor,new records,all records

scan  #1 =>0 2 ['3', '4']
Total Records scanned :2
```

Everything is fine upto now.when I insert four more new data say (6,6) (7,7) (8,8) (9,9) and start the scanning the data with `start_cursor = 5` same as example :2 
I am missing some of the data say (6) is missed here.

```
Example : 3
start_cursor=5
```

```
scan #=>Cursor,new records,all records

scan  #1 =>3 3 ['3', '4', '9']
scan  #1 =>0 2 ['3', '4', '9', '7', '8']
Total Records scanned :5
```

Whether redis scan will scan data inserted after scan operation started ? If not is there is any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees):

> Elements that were **not constantly present** in the collection during a full iteration, may be returned or not: it is undefined.

Since the data is inserted after the scan operation starts, these data is **NOT CONSTANTLY PRESENT**. So `SCAN` doesn't guarantee to return the newly inserted data.

> If not is there is any other way to achieve this?

AFAIK, there's no other way to achieve that.